# Angular installing app-module looks in local users folder

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Bear with me. There is so many new technologies for me here. So I am not sure whether this is an npm, adal or Angular question.

I am trying to create a project with Angular 6 and ADAL.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/microsoft-adal-angular6

According to the sample I need to install an app-routing module.

For this I followed:
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5

How I get following error:

```
C:\Users\xx\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\WebApplication18>ng generate module app-routing --flat --module=appng generate module app-routing --flat --module=app
```

> Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
>   Error: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
>       at WorkspaceLoader._getProjectWorkspaceFilePath (C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\workspace-loader.js:44:19)
>       at WorkspaceLoader.loadWorkspace (C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\workspace-loader.js:31:21)

For some reason it looks in my users folder for the *angular.json* file, and not the current folder. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your cli is confused.

try this:
`npm run -- ng generate module app-routing --flat --module=app`

NPM will run the cli which is installed in `node_modules`.